# php max_execution_time not working in laravel app

Tags: php, laravel-5, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to upload files using `laravel` app. The file was large so its take some time to process in controller. After 30 seconds request was cancelled. Then i changed `max_execution_time` = 30 to `max_execution_time` = 500 and restart apache2 service.its reflect in `phpinfo()` but its still cancelled after 30 seconds. whats wrong with me? please help me.

Here is phpinfo()

[image]

Comment: did you that in your .htaccess file?

Comment: Nope. Where is exist .htaccess file ?

Comment: try to change `max_input_time` also in php.ini file

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR i changed max_input_time but its still cancelled.

Comment: You can add one yourself and put there `max_execution_time`

Comment: **SHow us the REAL Error message from you error log**

Comment: @KaushikMakwana check this [link](http://www.rajamm.info/2008/09/22/magic-with-htaccess-file-increase-execution-time-session-expiry-time-and-file-upload-size-limit/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set value specifically for your project using htaccess, so that you don't have to override php.ini everytime.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 9999M
php_value post_max_size 9999M
php_value max_execution_time 9999M

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i added your suggestion in public/.htaccess but its still error. i need to restart anything ?

Comment: Yes restart apache mysql